# HashMap value is not changing

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, event-handling

[image: Edit class frame]

I want to enter name/id of an item stored in HashMap and edit its values accordingly.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Items {
    String name;
    int id;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    public static Map<Integer, Items> items = new HashMap<>();

    Items(String name, int id, int quantity,float price){
        this.name = name;
        this.id=id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        items.putIfAbsent(this.id,this);
    }
}
```

Following line of code is from the *ActionListener* class in *actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)*

```java
if(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()==1&&(nameRadioButton.isSelected())||idRadioButton.isSelected())
{
        for(Integer i : Items.items.keySet())
        {
            if(inputText.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(Items.items.get(i).name))  //inputText is first JTextField
            {
                Items.items.get(i).name = inputText.getText();  //possible error 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `Items.items.get(i).name = inputText.getText();` - this line is weird: you pick the hash entry having the same value (ignoring case) with the input text and you change the value to the value of input text. what's the point of changing the hash value if it is already equal to the input text value?

Comment: @mangusta *facepalm. It should've been = newInputText.getText(). Issue resolved, thanks.